# Canadian Greyhound - how to find what facilities are on a bus route?

Tags: canada, buses, electronic-items, greyhound

Word is that **Greyhound Canada** has revitalised some of their buses, and indeed my roommate mentioned that his bus from Vancouver to Whistler last week had wifi and charging points.

I'm wondering about the route I hope to take next week - from Vancouver to Calgary.  I'd like to know if there's a way to find out what facilities are onboard that bus on that route (or any route) - including wifi, power, leg-room, aircon and lights.

Comment: It maybe best to email them, if the bus fleet is newly introduced & all facilities are not available on all services http://www.greyhound.ca/en/contactus.aspx

Comment: http://www.greyhound.com/en/about/factsandfigures.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In 2010 (summer) they operated buses without plugs and wifi on their transcontinental line (Toronto-Vancouver). There was aircon (I don't remember it was too hot or cold on the bus).

They started operating brand new buses at that time, but kept them for other parts of their networks, I supposed it would be quite expensive to offer plugs and wifi on a line almost everyone had electronics or even a tablet.

Looking at the [list of buses](http://www.greyhound.com/en/about/factsandfigures.aspx) provided by @Karlson, the Vancouver-Calgary buses were the third model and the rest was operated with the last one.

About the lights and leg-room, I've rarely seen a bus without reading lights and the leg-room was not so spacious (I'm tall and it was not very comfortable).

To summarize, I would not expect wifi or plugs on the bus if I were you.